# a way to trigger Sub Menus on hover instead of click?

Tags: javascript

for the menu widget / how can I have sub-menus trigger on HOVER instead of clicking ?!!!
if there is no what, how can I do this with custom code / perhaps JS ... ?

not sure hot to get to JS code used here / this is an WordPress , ELEMENTOR menu widget / and that's the HTML that goes around that sub-menu // is there any possible way to manipulate anything from this HTML to make a JS code that will trigger a click when that menu item is hovered ??

here is the code from my developer tools inspect element:

```
<a href="#" class="pp-menu-item has-submenu highlighted" id="sm-15751350229339702-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-15751350229339702-2" aria-expanded="true">My Prescription<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>

<ul class="sub-menu pp-advanced-menu--dropdown sm-nowrap" id="sm-15751350229339702-2" role="group" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="sm-15751350229339702-1" aria-expanded="true" style="z-index: 3; width: auto; min-width: 10em; display: block; max-width: 1000px; top: auto; left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-407"><a href="https://www.hyatt.icodetheweb.com/refillrx/" class="pp-sub-item">RefillRX</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-408"><a href="https://www.hyatt.icodetheweb.com/transferrx/" class="pp-sub-item">TransferRX</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post the current JavaScript that you're using to trigger the click.

Comment: not sure hot to get to that / this is an WordPress , ELEMENTOR menu widget / and that's the HTML that goes around that sub-menu // is there any possible way to manipulate anything from this HTML to make a JS code that will trigger a click when that menu item is hovered ??

Comment: How would the hover work on touch-devices?

Comment: if clicked on then ! on mobile

Comment: My point is, that there's a reason why menu items are activated on click rather than on hover, in order for them to be accessible through all devices. If you try to use hover, you will be dealing with several accessibility issues and extra conditional logic (depending on the device and the event triggeres) that might not be worth the go. Just a thing that you should take into consideration before choosing the hover approach.

Comment: thanx for the info and that does make sense / but I'd like to know if this can actually be done using JS ? and if so, it be good to learn how to do so / juss to keep it as an option if needed one day,